# boot-repair issues after ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS install

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I was having Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alognside Windows 10 on my Dell XPS 8930 Desktop for years. Then i decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.
All the fun began after [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243328/dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-linux-18-04-lts-upgrade-to-20-04lts-kernel-5-4-is)

Then somehow i got Ubutnu 20.4 LTS working but it was not recognizing the Ethernet internet [also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267569/ubuntu-linux-20-04-lts-couldnt-recognize-ethernet-internet-as-well-as-graphics).

For both the questions - I followed like anything but not much luck so decided to install Ubuntu 20.4 LTS all over again.

But when i tried installing from live USB, I faced this choice-either erase 20.4 LTS and reinstall or Install 20.4.1 LTS along side 20.4 LTS
[image]
and then
[image]

after all this install - I was asked to reboot(take out the media)...but i was getting this black grub screen
[image]

prior to installing 20.4.1 LTS, my ubutnu paritions were like this on my nvme drive
[image]
[image]

Searched around and tried boot-repair from the live USB following this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232488/black-screen-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04-lts)
When i tried boot-repair - I got the issue in terms of turning off Legacy boot which i did.
This is my [boot-repair pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QV4DFpYbtV/)

After that boot-repair worked fine - I have to follow a lot of recommended commands and it worked fine.
In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

```
You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.

If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Reboot worked.

Was able to get a regular grub screen and boot to both Windows 10 and Ubutnu 20.4.1 LTS but no 20.4 LTS
But the new issue is that I have 20.4 LTS(installed on nvme) and 20.4.1 LTS installed on /dev/sda7 and /dev/sda8
[image]
[image]

I just want to keep Ubuntu on my nvme drive and not any where else.

[image: Grub customizer screen shot]

This is my BIOS  - how it looks like
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are mixing UEFI and BIOS, which you really cannot do. Your system is UEFI. Your Windows install is UEFI with gpt partitioning. But your NVMe drive is MBR partitioned and has BIOS grub in MBR. But you now have an Ubuntu UEFI boot entry in ESP on Windows drive. Only boot in UEFI boot mode. And best to convert NVMe to gpt and reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. how you boot install media is how it installs. You may need to partition in advance. UEFI/gpt partitioning, but now use swap file http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: @oldfred - thanks - that's very useful - how to uninstall the existing ones - I don't know whether i have one 20.4.1 LTS or two? Also the liveUSB should be created within Ubuntu so that it uses gpt not MBR paritioned(this part i was not aware and not very sure of)?

Comment: Partition type of live installer usually is not critical. Although some tools that create installer only create BIOS with MBR and UEFI with gpt. You do not have to use Ubuntu to create live installer, just make sure it is UEFI bootable and that you then boot it in UEFI mode. With two drives, you always want to partition in advance, with gpt & an ESP and use Something Else to install, if Ubuntu on separate drive. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair