# Deleted Ubuntu and grub but Windows 10 is not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)
to remove Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS and grub2 - the answer with the most upvotes.
After that grub2 black screen is gone but Windows 10 is not booting.
[image: This is my Windows PC BIOS]
[image: and this is the BIOS error message after Dell diagnostics is done]

**Update1**

I logged in using live USB and then tried boot-repair.
Followed all the recommendations by it. It tried to reinstall grub2 so there seems to be another Ubuntu Linux 20.4 some where being installed on my computer(I have 1 NVME PCIe drive where Ubuntu Linux was installed - which i deleted, then 1 SSD where Windows is installed i.e. Windows C drive and then two hard drives for Windows D and E). It seems somewhere on C, D or E - ubuntu linux is installed and i want to get rid of it OR move to PCIe NVME drive
Here is the boot-repair output [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rQ3cTyr9Wn/) and contents from boot-repair activity:

```
You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS entry (sdb2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.

If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

### Here is the gparted view from my Ubuntu Linux 20.4 LTS
[image]

### [image]

### [image]

### [image]

There is somehow hidden Ubuntu 20.4 LTS being installed some where else also which is making my grub to boot into Ubuntu 20.4 LTS Linux.

**Update 2**
After some more searching and digging, found that another copy of Ubuntu Linxu 20.4.1 LTS is installed on /dev/sda7
[image]

and also confirmed by `df` command

```
root@ashu-XPS-8930:/home/ashu# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            32757028       0  32757028   0% /dev
tmpfs            6557040    2188   6554852   1% /run
/dev/sda7       95099332 8980340  81245112  10% /
tmpfs           32785188  126668  32658520   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           32785188       0  32785188   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         98944   98944         0 100% /snap/core/9804
/dev/loop1          9344    9344         0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
/dev/loop2         56320   56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop5         30720   30720         0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop4        261760  261760         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop3         63616   63616         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop6         51072   51072         0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/sda2          98304   61255     37049  63% /boot/efi
tmpfs            6557036      20   6557016   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs            6557036      32   6557004   1% /run/user/1000
```

**Update 3**
Even after deleting /dev/sda7 partition from Windows and then deleting /EFI/ubuntu - i was not able to make Windows 10 boot.
Thus used the live USB drive to copy the important data from Windows C: into Windows D:
Later used the Windows recovery drive to reinstall the Windows on C: drive. I could have installed it on other drive but my C: is SSD and i prefer installing OS and apps on faster media.

Comment: You really should not have even had to do that.  Perhaps you deleted more than you should?  If you delete the EFI or any of the Microsoft system partitions, that would result in inability to boot

Comment: @Nmath - I deleted only my /EFI/ubuntu parition and nothing else. Microsoft, Dell and other partitions are already there. If entire /EFI was deleted - how i can login to Windows back?

Comment: At power-on, select the EFI menu (some key like f12 or f10, etc.) to get the selection of devices or oses to boot. Select Windows.  Change the bootorder in your BIOS to put Windows first to avoid having to do the EFI menu.

Comment: I am having "somewhere hidden ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS" with grub2 which is successfully booting either Windows 10 or Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS. What i am looking to do? I want to somehow delete the "hidden ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS" and then remove grub2 and then reinstall ubuntu from live usb onto my PCI NVME drive.

Comment: @Nmath - updated. Ubuntu Linux 20.4.1 is installed in /dev/sda7

Comment: If you're looking to find and delete all Ubuntu partitions, that looks like the one you've been searching for. As long as there is a detectable Ubuntu installation there, it will come up in boot-repair.

Comment: @Nmath - Planning to install Ubuntu 20.4.1 into /dev/nvme*. Yes you are right - even a single install of Ubuntu, boot-repair will find it. BTW, boot-repair is really good - much better than overall support I got from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the end this was not successful:

1. Remove ubuntu partitions from hard drives
2. Remove grub

only thing which worked was:
to install Windows 10(after trying 1 and 2) using the recovery media. Prior to that - I connected the data cable/Ubuntu live USB to take some back as Windows installation will wipe clean the C: Drive. Other drives - D and E were intact and require nothing from my side.

After that installed Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS alongside Windows 10 on my PCI NVME hard drive. Live USB was created to boot into UEFI mode and BIOS was with UEFI(disabled Legacy mode and secure boot also disabled).
Ubuntu Installation was totally smooth - everything running fine now.

Somehow for me dual boot Windows/Ubuntu - Ubuntu upgrade from previous LTS to new LTS release never happened successfully. Same happened when i tried to upgrade dual boot Windows 7 or 10/Ubutnu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. While inplace Windows upgrade worked fine.

[image: Installed on nvme drive]